# How to access svn repo using ruby in svn_wc

Tags: ruby, svn, rubygems

I am using svn_wc.
It gives err as  no such file to load -- svn/core (LoadError)
what to do?

Comment: Please submit the specific code that you're using and the true error message.

Comment: @AdamB - He is probably trying to use something like the example given in the usage section here - https://github.com/dvwright/svn_wc I got the same error too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The above answer is a link only answer and can become useless when the link is dead. Dumping the link contents here -

SVN 1.5.1 / Ruby bindings on Windows
Rather than messing around with compiling swig bindings etc:

```
Download the ruby bindings from the svn site: (http://subversion.tigris.org/files/documents/15/43245/svn-win32-1.5.1_rb.zip)

From the zip - copy ruby\lib\svn into c:\ruby\lib\ruby\site_ruby\1.8\svn

From the zip – copy ruby\ext\svn\ext into c:\ruby\lib\ruby\site_ruby\1.8\svn\ext

copy libeay32.dll and ssleay32.dll from your subversion 1.5 directory into c:\ruby\bin

run irb and test with: require ‘svn/core’
```

> Where can I find updated binaries? I've looked around on the
>   Subversion site, but there seems to be no link.
>
> They are available on the subversion site here: svn-win32-1.5.5_rb.zip
>   If you go to the subversion site and select windows binaries for
>   apache 2.2 you will see the list.
>
> I just over-wrote the two DLL files (libeay32 and ssleay32) that came
>   with my ruby 1.8.6 installation with the two that came with my svn
>   1.5.5 installation. (Yes, I saved the originals.)This was necessary to passing the "require 'svn/core'" test, but is this likely to have
>   broken something within ruby?
>
> Hey Ramon, i'd hope not but you never know :) The dll's are OpenSSL
>   libraries so if you see any weird behaviour when using any ssl related
>   functionality in ruby, that'd probably be the culprit

Answer (score 0):

Ruby can't find svn/core in your installation, if you look at [the github page for svn_wc](https://github.com/dvwright/svn_wc) the requirements are listed as:

> Requires that the Subversion (SWIG) Ruby Bindings are installed

Which is much easier to do on Linux and OSX than on [Windows](http://danintouch.blogspot.com/2008/08/svn-151-ruby-bindings-on-windows.html)

Comment: Error cause: svn library for ruby was not installed. 

I ran `apt-get install libsvn-ruby` and it worked! 

Thanks